# Remove a Group header from a dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use this code to group items for my dropdownlist control:

```
var item;

var GroupsGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>', {
    label: 'Groups'
}).appendTo(selectControl);

var EmployeesGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>', {
    label: 'Employees'
}).appendTo(selectControl);

jQuery('option', selectControl).each(function (i) {
    item = jQuery(this);

    if (item.attr("class") == 'Employees') {
        item.appendTo(EmployeesGRP);
    }
    else {
        item.appendTo(GroupsGRP);
    }

});
```

And the output of this is:

```
Employees
  Employee number one
  Employee number two
Groups
  Group number one
  Group number two
```

Question:

how can i remove the Group header if there no items?

Comment: If you have `options` then only it will create `optgroup` Right? Can you show your code online like on `fiddle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrapAll on the options with classes you want grouped, and the rest will remain ungrouped:

Assuming your html is:

```
<SELECT id="MainContent_DropDownList1">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option class="Employees">Employee number one</option>
    <option class="Employees">Employee number two</option>
    <option class="Groups">Group number one</option>
    <option class="Groups">Group number two</option>
    <option>Not an employee or group</option>
</SELECT>
```

And the jquery:

```
$(function() {

    var EmployeesGRP = $('<optgroup/>');
    var GroupsGRP = $('<optgroup/>');

    EmployeesGRP .attr('label', 'Employees');
    GroupsGRP .attr('label', 'Groups');

    $('#MainContent_DropDownList1 .Employees').wrapAll(EmployeesGRP);
    $('#MainContent_DropDownList1 .Groups').wrapAll(GroupsGRP);

});
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqFWp/)

Comment: i dont't want to unwrap any item, what i want to achieve is, if the Employees for example doesnt have any item, i want the Employees header to be removed @DavidG

Comment: If you look at the jsFiddle live example, delete the 2 Employee options from the SELECT statement and you'll see no group header will show for Employees.

Comment: indeed it is! :) how stupid of me not checking first, thanks very much for this @ DavidG